# How to change field name in LibreOffice Base?

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice, database

I have table as shown below

[image: Image link]

Then I tried to format the field.

[image: image link]

Why there is no option to change the name? It is possible to change the field name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the table layout (which includes field names) *when in table data view*. Just close the data view, right-click on the table name and select edit:

[image]

This will open the **table design view** which allows for editing field names:

[image]